# salesforce "customobject" tooling api returns more records than what seeing in the system overview

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api

The "CustomObject" tooling API returns more records than what i am seeing in the System Overview UI.
Can someone please explain the reason for it, thanks.
API response:
[image]

System Overview:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

System Overview includes all your custom objects and custom settings except those from AppExchange managed packages. This total can include objects from unmanaged packages or unpublished apps. This is by design. It also seems to exclude hierarchical custom settings, custom metadata, platform events etc.

In contrast, "CustomObject" tooling API would include all of these in its result. You should check if there are managed package custom objects, platform events etc. in your org and try to tally up the numbers.